# Explanation of this proof of distribution of molecules after collision

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

The below excerpt is taken from Section no.4 from "The Feynman Lectures on Physics Vol.1 Ch.39" ([here is the link to the exact text](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_39.html#Ch39-S4)). Here Sir Richard Feynman tries to explain and "prove" that the distribution of the molecules after collision in a gas will be such that it will be equally likely to find any pair moving in any direction in space.

> Ultimately, what will be the distribution? Answer: It will be equally likely to find any pair moving in any direction in space. After that further collisions could not change the distribution.
>
> They are equally likely to go in all directions, but how do we say that? There is of course no likelihood that they will go in any specific direction, because a specific direction is too exact, so we have to talk about per unit “something.” The idea is that any area on a sphere centered at a collision point will have just as many molecules going through it as go through any other equal area on the sphere. So the result of the collisions will be to distribute the directions so that equal areas on a sphere will have equal probabilities.
>
> Incidentally, if we just want to discuss the original direction and some other direction an angle θ
> from it, it is an interesting property that the differential area of a sphere of unit radius is sinθdθ
> times 2π
> (see Fig. 32–1). And sinθdθ
> is the same as the differential of −cosθ. So what it means is that the cosine of the angle θ between any two directions is equally likely to be anything from −1 to +1
> .

I am unable to understand the first part of this explanation as he states that we have to talk about per unit "something" and that to prove the above written statement we have to show that the result of the collisions will be to distribute the directions so that equal areas on a sphere will have equal probabilities. Although isn't this idea itself made on the fact that there will a uniform number of molecules per unit "something" in all directions of the collision which in my opinion defeats the point of this proof/explanation as "that is" the thing we have to explain in the first place.

My guess is that there could be a hidden assumption like a large number of particles with high collision rates leading to a large number of particles in all directions (assuming we don't know the distribution in any particular direction initially and that it be variable) so that in effect the small differences in the number of particles may not matter and then due to the symmetery of a sphere equal areas would indeed have equal probabilites. Is this assumption correct or just entirely incorrect? Also is there anything obvious that I am overlooking or missing or else is there something I am failing to realise?

Comment: Try molecular chaos or BBGKY hierarchy?